# What options to xargs will make it work with lines rather than words

Tags: xargs

I want to use `xargs` (or similar concept) on lines with spaces.  In effect, if the input has

```
line one
line two
line three
...
```

and I call `xargs` such as `cat f | xargs foo`, then I want `xargs` to execute `foo "line one" "line two" "line three" ...` for as many arguments that fit on a command line.

Currently I do this using the shell such as

```
cat list | while read f ; do foo $f ; done
```

but that calls `foo` for each line and it would be a bit more efficient if `foo` is called with a list rather than just one argument.

The `-I` option, as documented, sounds like what I want but in my case (Free BSD), it is calling `foo` with only one argument.  `-L` and `-R` don't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace newlines with nulls:

```
cat list | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 foo
```

Comment: Excellent!  But is it single quotes or double quotes for tr?  Oh, I guess tr will convert the \n and \0.